# why is my HTML not working

Tags: css, html

This is my HTML code

```css
body {
  font-family: verdana;
  background-color: green;
  background: url("https://dncache-mauganscorp.netdna-ssl.com/thumbseg/729/729951-bigthumbnail.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.pc {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#pcr {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.red {
  style=" color: yellow: font-size: 25px"
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>MANIDY</title>

  <body>
    <h1 class=pc> MANIDY </h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I open that, the screen is just white, I use this template to make all my pages and it just started not working.

I use chrome, I have used this before to make my other webpages its just my template.

Comment: You've also got some syntax errors in CSS

Comment: `.red { style=" color: yellow: font-size: 25px" }` What?!

Comment: working fine for me

Comment: it works... you just have a big ass background image that takes some time to load and everything else is white.. https://plnkr.co/edit/LShHRuxI9wfWXgqcalwX?p=preview

Comment: Click the run code snippet button.

Comment: [edit] your snippet. Before clicking Save and Insert, click the Tidy button. Save us all some time trying to read that code...

Answer (score 2):

Because you never close `<head>` and you forgot to properly wrap your **pc** class within the body of your web page.

Also your CSS for `.red` makes no sense, it should be:

```
.red {
    color: yellow;
    font-size: 25px;
 }
```

**Whole Code**

```css
body {
  font-family: verdana;
  background: green url("https://dncache-mauganscorp.netdna-ssl.com/thumbseg/729/729951-bigthumbnail.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.pc {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#pcr {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.red {
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>MANIDY</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1 class="pc">MANIDY</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Actually, in the HTML spec, [unquoted attributes are valid](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attr-unquoted); so the `<h1 class=pc>` is not incorrect.

Comment: Ok, but it is bad style, because he cannot add multiple classes this way